# Python pandas read file with delimiters inside the data?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text

I regularly have to read text files as such:

```
Column1; Column2; Column3

data1;dat;a2;data3
```

Meaning that the data in Column 2 uses the same character used as the delimiter, therefore pandas incorrectly reads this data as two columns. This is just an illustrative example, this is not the real data.

How do I efficiently overcome this? I don't know a way besides manually editing the text file, but this becomes highly inefficient very fast.

Edit:
Best preemptive knowledge I can have is predicting which columns are likely to have delimiters. For example, I could realistically guess beforehand that column 2 will have delimiters in the text.

Comment: That's malformed CSV. What's generating these files? Can you fix that instead?

Comment: In this example, the actual delimiters also have spaces. Is that true for your real-world data? Then you could use a regex `sep`.

Comment: I have no control over the quality of the files received.

Comment: @wjandrea no spaces in my data, I had them for ease of reading on here. I've removed them

Comment: @JonSG I think you misunderstood the question. The semicolon is also part of the data. If you naively do `sep=';'`, then `data1` ends up in the index instead of `Column1`. If you fix that with `index_col=[]`, you get `ParserError: Expected 3 fields in line 2, saw 4`.

Comment: yes, my bad. I assumed it was a separator thing not a column values thing

Comment: The point is that it's UNknown which field holds the `;`: what if the 1st column is `data1;dat` or the 2nd is `dat;a2` or maybe the 3rd column is `a2;data3` ?

Comment: Outside the context of programming, how would you determine that the second column was not `dat` but `dat;a2` or that the first column is `data1` not `data1;dat`? Perhaps knowing how you would parse that row, we could help you automate that.

Comment: In this example, the data values all have lengths of at least 5, and they start with a letter and end with a number. Is that true of your real-world data? Then you could write a pre-processor. What I'm more broadly trying to ask is, is there any consistency to the data that would let you distinguish an actual delimiter from a "fake" one?

Comment: @wjandrea this is an example of the issue, please do not take it as a literal example of my data. I have text with delimiters mixed inside, that's about it.

Comment: @JonSG If I knew how to correctly parse this I wouldn't ask the question.

Comment: What I CAN DO is estimate the column that has the bad data. Say I know beforehand that column 2 will have delimiters inside it, what can I do with this?

Comment: Read each row of data as a string and split the row on the delimiter. Now count the resulting columns. If it is more than expected merge two of the columns based on where you believe the bad data lives.

Comment: @PJ_ Totally. What I was trying to say is, this example has a pattern to it, which you could exploit. But if the real data doesn't, that answers my question. Anyway, Jon's approach sounds good; that's exactly what I thought too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue with the following code. Only prerequisite is that you have an idea of the columns that will be malformed:

```
all_corrected = []  # list to hold all corrected text lines

bad_col = 2  # index of bad column
prev_col = bad_col - 1

with open('malformed.txt') as file:
    header = file.readline().strip().split(';')

    for line in file:
        temp_line = line.strip().split(';')
        correct_line = temp_line[:prev_col] + [';'.join(temp_line[prev_col:bad_col+1])] + temp_line[bad_col+1:]

        all_corrected.append(correct_line)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(all_corrected, columns=header)
```

This code is based on [Serge Ballesta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43252397/12417488) on [Issue with delimiter inside column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251122/python-issue-with-delimiter-inside-column-data). Thanks to @wjandrea and @JonSG for the support.

Comment: Nice! Two minor things I would change: 1) Define `sep = ';'` and use that instead of a [magic constant](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants). 2) You don't really need to create `correct_line` when you can just modify `temp_line`, like `temp_line[prev_col] = ';'.join(temp_line[prev_col:bad_col+1]); del temp_line[bad_col]`.