# Remove rows which has more than 4 columns using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

l have several csv files that l process with pandas. l would like to remove rows that have more than 3 columns.

How can l proceed ?

Thank you

**Edit1**

```
  id                                       ocr  raw_value   
4a82a357-99e7-49e6-85b6-b2f6a27b8d5f    OMNIPAGE    Terms        em
8b549fef-0cda-4af5-8239-35153c33ffbc    OMNIPAGE    price   
52ffe66a-b1ab-4b22-9b26-c298d53c951c    OMNIPAGE    Renseignements  
507a0d96-9481-4b3f-8c35-f16588bedc0b    OMNIPAGE    pour    
52e171dc-8d22-4162-b748-692b2fc11659    OMNIPAGE    Client  
c40a7e9f-1ec4-4cac-87e8-02ed0f335fe9    OMNIPAGE    5           client
4a936ed7-c082-4f46-9fa1-761a1525e2df    OMNIPAGE    SAS 
4b78130e-b099-400c-b7bf-6470e0519783    OMNIPAGE    des 
4d5c6297-1c79-42f9-b4ea-929a9abfb3f7    OMNIPAGE    431 
829d8bf5-b251-4bb1-82d8-0e912ab64e8e    OMNIPAGE    59  102
5ed5b74d-efc5-49fa-9b12-dbe3ca88995f    OMNIPAGE    votre   votre
58d26125-1120-4328-83c4-7f5b0135184d    OMNIPAGE    Crécy,  Crécy,
```

In this example : first row and 6th row to be removed  they have extra column **em** , **client**

Comment: Each row in a particular dataframe should have the same number of columns. Please post an example.

Comment: Could you please share an example?

Comment: @user55449  please see my update

Comment: @MedAli, please see my update

Comment: @vincent what's the separator for the CSV files?

Comment: the separater is sep=","

Comment: change your title to **more than 3 columns**

Comment: @vincent based on your description the separator should be "\t" (tabulation). Anyways, if you add error_bad_lines=False to pd.read_csv it will skip all lines that cause an error.

Comment: @MedAli, why should the operator be tabulation ?   what if l put df=pd.read_csv("file.csv",sep=",",error_bad_lines=False)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible error is the extra column only. Then pass this in pd.read_csv.

```
error_bad_lines=False
```

> error_bad_lines : boolean, default True Lines with too many fields
>   (e.g. a csv line with too many commas) will by default cause an
>   exception to be raised, and no DataFrame will be returned. If False,
>   then these “bad lines” will dropped from the DataFrame that is
>   returned. (Only valid with C parser)

Comment: Hi, error_bad_lines is supposed to remove rows with empty columns ?

Comment: @vincent updated the answer.
Refer this for more help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440805/pandas-dataframe-read-csv-on-bad-data

Comment: Thank you it woks

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are supposed to have a fixed number of columns. Pandas is not a CSV format validator (even if it is able to handle a few mistakes).
If you have a improperly formatted CSV (in your case, with variable number of rows in each column), you should prevalidate it before feeding it to Pandas.

For example: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csvvalidator

Or code to do it yourself is rather trivial.