# Split a CSV if specific string in row is found (Python/Pandas/Bash)

Tags: pandas, bash, csv, split, header

I've got one crappy CSV file with multiple headers inside it. It looks like this:

```
File1:
    #HEADER COL1 COL2
    data
    data
    data
    #HEADER COL1 COL2 COL3
    data
    data
    data
    data
    data
    #HEADER COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
    data
    data
    ...
```

Since I can't load it with pandas due to the in-the-file-headers, I'm looking to split the data at each header to a separate file (or separate data frames in pandas). Is there a way to do this?

This CSV is generated by sensors. If a sensor is added, the header will get a new column. This could also happen in the in-the-file-headers. So it is NOT a solution to delete those headers.
([Clean wrong header inside Dataframe with Python/Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808795/clean-wrong-header-inside-dataframe-with-python-pandas))

It would be really nice to do it in python/pandas, but I would also be happy with a bash command/script solution.

Expected output:

```
File1:
        #HEADER COL1 COL2
        data
        data
        data
File2:
        #HEADER COL1 COL2 COL3
        data
        data
        data
        data
        data
File3:
        #HEADER COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
        data
        data
        ...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to show your expected output as well as what you've tried ?

Comment: Are those `HEADER` lines always the same? Can you post a realistic input?

Comment: No the HEADER lines can change (but they all start with "#"). So if I could locate "#", I could split the files

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^#HEADER/{close(FILENAME "_" c); c++} {print > (FILENAME "_" c)}' file
```

will split input `file` into `file_n` parts, where n is the section counter.

Comment: in my case this just worked beautifully! `awk '/^#/{close(FILENAME "_" c); c++} {print > (FILENAME "_" c)}' file`

Comment: last question: how can I export the result file to another folder?

Answer (score 1):

With convenient **`csplit`** command (to split a file into sections by pattern):

```
csplit -b %d -f file -z input_file '/#HEADER.*/' '{*}'
```

Viewing results:

```
$ head file[0-9]
==> file0 <==
#HEADER COL1 COL2
data
data
data

==> file1 <==
#HEADER COL1 COL2 COL3
data
data
data
data
data

==> file2 <==
#HEADER COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
data
data
...
```