# Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 93, saw 8

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

Using pandas and numpy to read an excel file and create sql table upon said excel file... everything in the code seems to work find besides the error I get when encoding the source file

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# Import CSV
data = pd.read_csv (r"C:\Users\c.stembridge\OneDrive - NEWREST GROUP SERVICES\Overtime Forecast Report.xlsx", sep=',', encoding='cp437')   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Connect to SQL Server
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;UID=SA;PWD=Working@2022;DATABASE=testdb;Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=yes")
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create Table
cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE Overtime_Forecast (
            date nvarchar(10) primary key,
            day nvarchar(9),
            hrs int,
            dl int,
            catered int,
            hrs_diff_btwn_last_day int,
            catered_flight_diff int,
            employees_OT_count int,
            carriers int,
            full int,
            half int,
            total_carts int
            )
               ''')

# Insert DataFrame to Table
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Overtime_Forecast (
                        date nvarchar(10) primary key,
            day nvarchar(9),
            hrs int,
            dl int,
            catered int,
            hrs_diff_btwn_last_day int,
            catered_flight_diff int,
            employees_OT_count int,
            carriers int,
            full int,
            half int,
            total_carts int)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ''',
                row.date,
                row.day,
                row.hrs,
                row.dl,
                row.catered,
                row.hrs_diff_btwn_last_day,
                row.catered_flight_diff,
                row.employees_OT_count,
                row.carriers,
                row.full,
                row.half,
                row.total_carts
                )
conn.commit()
```

can't seem to figure out what could solve the errors as I used many solutions from other questions to get this far

Comment: The column names in your DataFrame appear to match the column names in the table so you may as well keep things simple and just use [df.to_sql(…, if_exists="append")](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to insert the rows.

Comment: This seems like an error that you would get from `read_csv`.  Is it?  If so, check this out for some options:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440805/pandas-dataframe-read-csv-on-bad-data/72051042#72051042