# Error tokenizing data > How to removed extra \t in a row or line in a data(CSV)

Tags: python, pandas

First, I already run through several question and answers here about my problem (Error tokenizing data) but I haven't got any working answer because I think my issue is not the same with the one I read.

I have a tab separated data (saved as .xls file) and be able to read thru pandas read_csv but encountered error on specific line during parsing.
The data consist of ~58K rows with blank row every other row.

Sample if opened in excel:
[image]

When reading the file through read_csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv('8176.xls', header=None, sep='\t', encoding='cp1252')
```

And this give an error: **ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 13245, saw 13**

I read several thread that this could be an header error or a separator error.

I was able to locate the row/line which is encountering error through running my read_csv with **nrows**  and it was in line 6623 of the data.

```
df = pd.read_csv('8176.xls', header=None, sep='\t', encoding='cp1252', nrows=6623)
```

Through readlines, I think this is the one causing the error:

There is unwanted tab delimiter (\t) inserted on this line:
[image]

The same issue when opening the file in excel, the data in that cell is splited and shifted by 1 column.
[image]

But when opening the file in notepad, it is only a space character not a Tab.
[image]

Is there any work around to eliminate the unwanted \t?

Or any encoding to read this as space only?

I already tried different encoding but also encountered errors.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you post a link to the file in the question?

Comment: There are two more functions in pandas for working with tables in txt files - pd.read_table and pd.read_fwf. Maybe what will help?

Comment: I'll check the pd.read_table and pd.read_fwf. Here is the sample of file i'm trying to open using read_csv. `https://gofile.io/d/WaOmGF`. In my previous project, I also dealt with .xls file with html formatting that's why I used pd.read_html.

Comment: While a workaround, but I succeeded. Saved the file as tab-delimited txt despite warnings and applied df = pd.read_table("8176.txt", encoding='cp1252'). Will suit you?

Comment: One last thing, one of my objectives here is to eliminate user intervention. Can i do it in python, the opening and saving the file as tab-delimited txt by using `open()` and `save()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this programmatically during `read_csv`. Check this answer out:

> Starting with pandas 1.4.0, read_csv() delivers capability that allows you to handle these situations in a more graceful and intelligent fashion by allowing a callable to be assigned to on_bad_lines=.

[Pandas dataframe read_csv on bad data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440805/pandas-dataframe-read-csv-on-bad-data/72051042#72051042)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to learn this one. I'll get back on you.