How do I move the next line (line 1125) separated from the preceding line (line 1124) in a csv file using python pandas?
Image of CSV line taken in Notepad++
I tried searching online but couldn't find a similar problem or solution. I'm thinking about iterating through each row in the csv file.
Please give me resources how I can solve this issue. Any answer is appreciated.
Here is the given output of the log:
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up.
Rows: 60431; errors: 82; max bad: 0; error percent: 0; reason: invalid, message: Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up.
Rows: 60431; errors: 82; max bad: 0; error percent: 0; reason: invalid, location: gs://openfoodfacts_objectstorage/data/FoodData_Central_foundation_food_csv_2023-10-26/food.csv, message:
**Error while reading data, error message: Missing close quote character (").;
line_number: 1124 byte_offset_to_start_of_line: 80843 column_index: 3 column_name: "description" column_type: STRING value: "Broccoli, steamed..." File: gs://openfoodfacts_objectstorage/data/FoodData_Central_foundation_food_csv_2023-10-26/food.csv;
  reason: invalid, location: gs://openfoodfacts_objectstorage/data/FoodData_Central_foundation_food_csv_2023-10-26/food.csv, message: Error while reading data, error message: Missing close quote character (").;
line_number: 1125 byte_offset_to_start_of_line: 80929 column_index:** 0 column_name: "string_field_0" column_type: STRING value: ",11.0,2019-04-01" File: gs://openfoodfacts_objectstorage/data/FoodData_Central_foundation_food_csv_2023-10-26/food.csv;
  reason: invalid, location: gs://openfoodfacts_objectstorage/data/FoodData_Central_foundation_food_csv_2023-10-26/food.csv, message: Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse input string "7/19/2023";
line_number: 55227 byte_offset_to_start_of_line: 4634498 column_index: 5 column_name: "publication_date" column_type: DATE value: "7/19/2023" File: gs://openfoodfacts_objectstorage/data/FoodData_Central_foundation_food_csv_2023-10-26/food.csv;
  reason: invalid, location: gs://openfoodfacts_objectstorage/data/FoodData_Central_foundation_food_csv_2023-10-26/food.csv, message: Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse input string "7/19/2023";
line_number: 55233 byte_offset_to_start_of_line: 4634875 column_index: 5 column_name: "publication_date" column_type: DATE value: "7/19/2023" File: gs://openfoodfacts_objectstorage/data/FoodData_Central_foundation_food_csv_2023-10-26/food.csv;
  reason: invalid, location: gs://openfoodfacts_objectstorage/data/FoodData_Central_foundation_food_csv_2023-10-26/food.csv


Why do you want to use pandas? There's no need. A CSV file is just line-oriented text. So, read all the lines into memory (a list), delete the relevant line from the list and rewrite the file

Your question is unclear, do you have the shown file and want to remove the newline? Please be explicit, provide a [mre] of the input and the matching expected output.

Okay I read this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440805/pandas-dataframe-read-csv-on-bad-data but not sure how to apply it on my case.

Why not just edit in Notepad++ which you are already using. No need for any code.

If you want to delete a line from a file and modify the file accordingly then:
def delete_line(filename, lineno):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r+") as data:
            lines = data.readlines()
            del lines[lineno]
            data.seek(0)
            data.writelines(lines)
            data.truncate()
    except IndexError:
        print("Not enough lines in the file")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

delete_line("foo.csv", 1125)


This is a CSV file, not a plain text file. Use a CSV parser to operate on decoded rows and individual fields (cells), and avoid bad code like this that could wreck the encoding.

@ZachYoung Please show an example of how this might fail the stated requirement

Hi SIGHUP. Your solution perfectly satisfies OP's request, but OP shouldn't have thought to delete line 1125 from their CSV any more than someone should reasonably think that deleting line X from a JSON or XML file will "fix" some error message about line X in said file. In their own answer they seem to have realized it was just a configuration issue with BigQuery.

Cutting line 1125 will leave the opening quote char on line 1124, which is the line that generates the error: line_number: 1124 byte_offset... Missing close quote character ("). So this solution: satisfies OP's request; breaks the file (leaving a non-terminated quote on line 1124); and would have resulted in the same error message from BigQuery. This isn't a solution for fixing a CSV file (which didn't need to be fixed in the first place); this is a general purpose line cutter which shouldn't be used with encoding schemes that can span multiple lines, like CSV does, like OP's file does.

If you look at my answer and that simple CSV I showed, and run delete_line("input.csv", 4), and try to reread the CSV with a strict decoder you'll definitely get an error. But the decoders I know (Python, Go) try to be lenient, and will just keep reading the malformed data.

I added job_config and allow_quoted_newlines to my code:
bigquery_load_cloud_storage(
        dataset=dataset_name,
        table=filename,
        uri=f"gs://{bucket_name}/data/{parentFolder}/{filename}.csv",
        gcp_credentials=gcp_credentials_block,
        job_config={
            "allow_quoted_newlines": True
        }
    )


Hi, Gabe. From my own research (linked in my answer), this makes sense. Did it work for you? If so, you can accept this answer for yourself.

For some reason your data has a quoted newline at line 1124, and BigQuery defaults to not expecting quoted newlines. Your solution of just adding that config option seems great.
If you did want or need to handle this yourself, as a preprocessing step, try Python's csv module. To replace all newlines in any field with a space:
import csv

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

for i, row in enumerate(data):
    for j, field in enumerate(row):
        data[i][j] = field.replace("\n", " ")

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)

The other suggestions to edit the CSV as text and manipulate lines without regard for the CSV encoding could (probably will) break your CSV file.
If you wanted to just get a report of issues your file might have before sending it to BigQuery (or another downstream processor), you can just inspect the rows and fields, like:
with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        for j, x in enumerate(row, start=1):
            if "\n" in x:
                print(
                    f"found newline in row {i} cell {j} (ending on line {reader.line_num}): {repr(row)}"
                )

On this small sample CSV (with a quoted newline between bar and baz, starting on line 4):
Col1,Col2
foo,bar
baz,biz
foo,"bar
baz"
nothing to see here,doh

that will print out:
found newline in row 3 cell 2 (ending on line 5): ['foo', 'bar\nbaz']

That print out also points out the distinction between what we think of as a row and the (maybe multiple) lines of raw text that can make up a row.
Also, my sample data has a header, which I don't like to count as row, so the i counter starts enumerating at 0 (for the header), and so the first row (foo,bar) becomes 1.
