Pandas read_csv() how to ignore lines which cannot be type cast
I have a CSV dataset which I'm trying to read into a DataFrame using pd.read_csv() but the CSV has a number of bad rows which can't be type cast to the types I'm expecting. Is there a way to skip all these rows within the read_csv() function?
The issue is that the CSV is 28,000 lines and the only way I know of to fix this is to read it line-by-line, adding each line into the DataFrame if it doesn't throw an error which would be more expensive than I'd like.

Edit: For anyone who is having the same issue, I have yet to find a native python/pandas solution but I do have one way of fixing it. Essentially I go through the file line-by-line and ensure that there are both the correct number of columns, and that each item can be cast to the correct type.
In testing, this was functionally impossible to do in python for performance reasons so I wrote a script in Rust using my admittedly beginner knowledge. The Rust program can be found here: https://github.com/reliquarion/csv-cleaner/tree/main.

Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72051042/2059294

Unfortunately the on_bad_lines kwarg which that post references only impacts behavior regarding lines with less than the requisite number of columns. I already have "on_bad_lines='skip'" but it doesn't have any effect on ValueErrors from invalid type casts.

*more than the requisite number
